# Finding index position of a value in r dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

abc and def are  r dataframes

```
abc <- as.data.frame(t(data.frame(
  a1 = c (1:5))))


def <- as.data.frame(t(data.frame(
  a1 = c (2.1:6.1))))
```

For every row value of 'def' dataframe, I want the corresponding index range in which it lies oinabc dataframe.

def[1,1] is 2.1 which lies between abc[1,2] and abc[1,3]

So for def[1,1], the corresponding value in a new dataframe 'xyz' would be (1,2),(1,3)

How to accomplish this?
I am new to R so thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this example makes sense? The value 4.1 appears between `abc[1, 4]` and `abc[1, 5]` but it also appears between `abc[2, 2]` and `abc[2, 3]`. This is also the case for 3.1. What should the result be if there is more than one answer? I suspect if you tell us more about what you are trying to do, there will be a better way to achieve it than this.

Comment: Modified the code example. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `findInterval`.

```
xyz <- vector("list", length = nrow(def))
for(i in seq.int(nrow(def))){
  x <- findInterval(def[i, ], as.matrix(abc)[i, ])
  xyz[[i]] <- cbind(paste0('(', i, ', ', x, ')'),
                    paste0('(', i, ', ', x + 1, ')'))
}

xyz
#[[1]]
#     [,1]     [,2]    
#[1,] "(1, 2)" "(1, 3)"
#[2,] "(1, 3)" "(1, 4)"
#[3,] "(1, 4)" "(1, 5)"
#[4,] "(1, 5)" "(1, 6)"
#[5,] "(1, 5)" "(1, 6)"
```

**Data**

```
abc <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:5, nrow = 1))
def <- as.data.frame(matrix(2.1:6.1, nrow = 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, if I understand what you're trying to do:

```
xyz <- sapply(def, function(x){
  mx1 <- max(which(abc[1,] < x[1]))
  mn1 <- min(which(abc[1,]> x[1]))
  mn1 <- ifelse(mn1 == Inf, NA, mn1)
  mx1 <- ifelse(mx1 == -Inf, NA, mx1)
  mx2 <- max(which(abc[2,] < x[2]))
  mn2 <- min(which(abc[2,]> x[2]))
  mn2 <- ifelse(mn2 == Inf, NA, mn2)
  mx2 <- ifelse(mx2 == -Inf, NA, mx2)
  
  c(paste0("(1, ", mx1, "), (1, ", mn1, ")"),
    paste0("(2, ", mx2, "), (2, ", mn2, ")")) 
    
  }
  )

xyz 
#           V1               V2               V3               V4                V5               
# [1,] "(1, 2), (1, 3)" "(1, 3), (1, 4)" "(1, 4), (1, 5)" "(1, 5), (1, NA)" "(1, 5), (1, NA)"
# [2,] "(2, 1), (2, 2)" "(2, 2), (2, 3)" "(2, 3), (2, 4)" "(2, 4), (2, 5)"  "(2, 5), (2, NA)"
```